# Having a hard time understanding redirecting / routing in laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel, redirect

I am completely stuck since two hours and definitely need your help. Disclaimer: I am not a coder - just a guy who is trying to mock up an idea.

So my page is actually working fine but I thought about moving content from a modal-popup to an actual sub-page. Meaning: If a user clicks on a button, some data points from the current page are being collected and passed to another view which shall be rendered using the data points as input.

EDIT: For clarification: The button is on /results.php where data is generated dynamically. The method should take some data points from here and generate a new view and render it at /buy.php or maybe at /buy/custom.php

My thoughts:

1. Normal redirect without parameters: Internal Link
2. Updating page-content without redirect but with parameters: Ajax

So combining my thoughts -> use ajax and return a new fresh view.

What I tried:

```
$("body").on("click", ".fa-shopping-cart", function() {

var $para1 = $(this).attr("data1");
var $para2 = $(this).attr("data2");
var $para3 = $(this).attr("data3");
var $para4 = $(this).attr("data4");

$.ajax({
url: "buy",
data: {
    a: $para1,
    b: $para2,
    c: $para3,
    d: $para4
},
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf_token"]').attr('content');
    if (token) {
       return xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-TOKEN', token);
    }
},
type: "post", 
success: function(response){ 
    console.log(response);
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
      console.log(JSON.stringify(jqXHR));
      console.log("AJAX error: " + textStatus + ' : ' + errorThrown);
}
});});
```

Routing:

```
Route::post('/buy', 'PageRouting@buy');
```

Controller:

```
public function buy()
{

    $para1= $_POST['a'];
    $para2 = $_POST['b'];
    $para3 = $_POST['c'];
    $para4 = $_POST['d'];

    // some magic to output $data

  return view('pages.buy', compact("data"));

}
```

buy.blade.php exists and displays $data with help of an foreach-loop.

So, when I first clicked the button the obvious happend:

The view ('pages.buy') is logged / displayed in my console in plain html and not rendered in the browser.

Now I am sitting here since two hours and I have no clue whatsoever. I read some blog post saying that you cannot redirect within an ajax-call. Unfortunately the post did not gave any hint on how to do it instead.

Can someone help me?

All best

Comment: The view ('pages.buy') is logged / displayed in my console in plain html and not rendered in the browser. - but on success response all you do is just console.log(response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace entire document with the response you have to use document.write but it's not the best thing to do. Why don't you use normal form submit if you need to return a view?

```
success: function(response){ 
    document.write(response);
},
```

P.S. if you want also to change the url, use the history manipulation functions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API

Comment: Can you use a form submit when you don't have a form? The data is in displayed in form of a table with 4 data points per row and a "get more info"-button. The button should if clicked find the 4 data points in this row and generate the other page. I have a look into the your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in your buy method -

```
public function buy ()
{
    ....//some stuff to get $data

    $html = view('pages.buy', compact("data"))->render();
    return response()->json([
        'success' => true,
        'html'    => $html
    ])
}
```

in your ajax success function

```
success: function(response){
    if(response.success)
    {
        $('#elementId').html(reponse.html) // or whatever you need
    } 

},
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your fast reply! The problem is I don't want to "update" a part of the page with the ajax-call, I want to go to another sub-page. Meaning: A User clicks on the button on www.example.com/results.php and is then, via the above method, redirected to www.example.com/buy.php, which is rendered based on some parameters which are dynamically generated in /results.php.

Comment: ok,so what first comes into my mind is do the following,after getting $data variable I think you need to put that into session and then just return some success of failure response based on if $data is correct,and if it's correct in your ajax success message you simply need to redirect to proper page -
window.location = "/buy"; and then just read data from session

Comment: I have look into your answer aswell. Thanks for the good idea!